# HTTPS 'GET' in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, amazon-s3

I am working on a mobile application using Cordova and AngularJS. I am struggling to run an HTTPS 'Get' call to an Amazon S3 server using the AngularJS $http service. The call fails with:

```
SSLHandshake: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

This is how I make my call to the S3 server:

```
$http({method: 'GET' , url: path});
```

The *path* variable is an HTTPS url to S3. This works fine if the URL is not HTTPS.
I also had this issue when working with the Cordova FileTransfer class, however I was able to solve it by setting *trustAllHosts* to true when starting the download. This cannot be done with the AngularJS $http service.

Does anybody know how I may solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AngularJS you should use `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);` to use secure URLs like HTTPS.

#### Example Code:

```
$scope.trustSrc = function (path) {
    if (path) {
        if (path.indexOf('https') === -1) {
            path = path.replace('http', 'https');
        }
    }
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(path);
};
```

This should return a secured path that could be used in your GET request like this:

```
$scope.trustedPath = $scope.trustSrc(path);
$http({method: 'GET' , url: trustedPath});
```

Comment: Thanks mate @phikry . I had actually tried `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` but I did not first replace `https` in the URL. It works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    getUser().then(function (response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        debugger;
    })

    function getUser() {
        return $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    }
```

Comment: dont forget to hold in array or object what you set data $scope.users = [];

Comment: It would also be good to add an explanation so the OP and others can understand what you are solving here.