# "Mixed Content" and "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" errors while trying to use SSL/HTTPS with angularjs http GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, https

I first implemented my site on a remote VPS without SSL, but then recently got certs from letsencrypt.org.

The site is now accessible at https://www.example.com but now all of my angularjs get requests:

```
var working_url = "http://www.example.com:3000";
$http.get(working_url+"/example01/").then(function(response){...});
$http.get(working_url+"/example02/").then(function(response){...});
```

began throwing this error in the inspection console:

`"Mixed Content ... the content must be served over HTTPS."`

I tried switching working_url from

```
var working_url = "http://www.example.com:3000";
```

to

```
var working_url = "https://www.example.com:3000";
```

and then got this error in the console:

`"net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"`

As per the accepted answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839524/how-can-i-use-https-in-angularjs), I tried adding a trailing '/' to all of my get URLs, but that didn't help.

I also tried @Kareem Elshahawy's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963115/https-get-in-angularjs), but that just throws "Error: [$http:badreq]"

What am I missing here?

I'm pretty new to all of this, so any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!